# What determines when the mutual friends notice appears on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friends

Why is it that "1 mutual friend" shows up only sometimes when I type in a certain contact's name in Facebook? Someone that I know "used" to be friends with someone else I know.

Does that mean they're still friends and I'm just blocked from seeing it now? Or is it because they "used" to be friends and it is just letting me know someone I know knows someone else I'm searching?

There are times I type this person's name in the search field and there isn't any mention of mutual friends.  I've also wondered if that means they're not "friends" anymore but are "messaging" back and forth when that appears.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more your question if still relevant? I read it twice and couldn't understand how this scenario is